# ffmpeg h264_amf usage in C++

Tags: c++, ffmpeg, h.264, libavcodec

I want to use h264_amf encoder in my C++ code. In FFmpeg command-line tool I can write
    `ffmpeg -i in_to_tree_1080p50.y4m -c:v h264_amf out.mp4`
And this works fine for me, but when I try to find this encoder by using `avcodec_find_encoder_by_name` I can't find it. My full code:

```
static AVCodec* select_codec() {
  static std::array<const char*, 6> codecs = {
    "h264_nvenc",
    "h264_amf",
    "h264_omx",
    "h264_v4l2m2m",
    "h264_vaapi",
    "h264_videotoolbox",
  };

  for (const char* name : codecs) {
    if (auto* codec = avcodec_find_encoder_by_name(name)) {
      std::cout << "Using " << name << " encoder" << std::endl;
      return codec;
    }
  }

  std::cout << "Using default h264 encoder" << std::endl;
  return avcodec_find_encoder(AV_CODEC_ID_H264);
}

int main() {
  select_codec();
  return 0;
}
```

The output of this function is always `Using default h264 encoder`. Did I do something wrong?

My configuration:

- FFmpeg 4.0
- Windows 10 x64
- MSVC17 (141 toolset)
- Radeon RX 470 Graphics

Answer (score 0):

You have to call av_register_all() before avcodec_find_encoder_by_name() and avcodec_find_encoder().

Comment: thx for answering, but I found that av_register_all() is a deprecated function (I use FFmpeg 4.0). Are there any other alternatives to register all encoders?

Comment: Apparently av_register_all() is not neccessary anymore since https://git.ffmpeg.org/gitweb/ffmpeg.git/commit/7e8eba2d8755962d9dca5eade57bf8f591a73c0c . So there must be another reason why your encoder is not found.  Is the command line ffmpeg and the version you link to the same?